# Slow performance with large stack and sparsehash

Tags: c++, hashset

I have a large stack of unsigned long long's (100M+) that I am trying to put into SparseHash, but the performance is very slow, as in for every 1k entries, it takes ~4-6 seconds on a MacBook Pro with 16Gb of RAM.

```
    while (stackUI.size()>0) {
       Set.insert(stackUI.top());
       stackUI.pop();
       if (stackUI.size()%1000==0) {
           cout<<stackUI.size()<<" "<<time(0)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my implementation, or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: A long time since I programmed in C++, but a couple of things that I would check: a) see if you can define the number of items of the set beforehand, so it does not goes expanding each few items introduced and b) reduce the number of calls to `stackUI.size()` (I doubt it is but it is easy to just store the value before the iteration and keep decrementing it).

Comment: Benchmark insertion for your sparse hash? http://sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/performance.html shows insertion to be pretty slow (not sure if it should be as slow as you're getting however).

Comment: @Dgrin91 He's doing it every 1000 entries... it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Are you using an stl container, and if so which one

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the performance with gcc hash_set?

Hash containers double their sizes and copy everything when the load factor goes high (like 0.5). Since you already know how many elements your hashset is going to hold (your stack size I guess), try reserving those many buckets before you start inserting. That way you will avoid re-hash and get a significant speedup.

Comment: I'm having difficulties figuring out how to predefine how big the hash_set should be. With sparse_hash, I was just defining the set, and then on the next line calling Set.resize(setSize)

Comment: Set.resize(stackUI.size()) just once before you start inserting into Set should do the trick.